# Cannot update llamaindex

Tags: python, pip, llama-index

After `llamaindex` introduced v0.10 in February 2024, it introduced a lot of breaking changes to imports. I am trying to update `llama-index` within a `conda` environment, but I receive the following error:

```
> pip install llama-index --upgrade
ERROR: Cannot install llama-index-cli because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    llama-index-vector-stores-chroma 0.1.4 depends on onnxruntime<2.0.0 and >=1.17.0
    llama-index-vector-stores-chroma 0.1.3 depends on onnxruntime<2.0.0 and >=1.17.0
    llama-index-vector-stores-chroma 0.1.2 depends on onnxruntime<2.0.0 and >=1.17.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

I have tried `pip install llama-index-vector-stores-chroma` but get the same error.

I have also tried installing `onnxruntime` but get this error:

```
pip install onnxruntime 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement onnxruntime (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for onnxruntime
```

How can I update `llama-index`?

Comment: Try this `py -m pip install llama-index`  Was Released: Feb 22, 2024

Comment: Conda doesn't seem pertinent. Dropping tag.

Comment: @toyotaSupra What does py -m do?

Comment: @merv It’s pip within a conda environment

Comment: `llama_index==0.10.8` just solved it for me e.g. via `pip install llama_index==0.10.8`

Comment: @Adam_G indeed. But it's just context here, akin to stating what OS you are on. It's great to document in the question body, but the tag is better reserved for when there is belief that those with Conda expertise would have special insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this using this workaround: `conda install onnxruntime -c conda-forge`. I got it from this thread: github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/11037

If there is a reason to not use the conda forge, please leave a comment.

Comment: thanks! this let me proceed with the installation

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue and it took me 4 hrs working with Llama-Index folks to get it working.

In terminal,

1. I had to deactivate conda's environment by `conda deactivate`
2. I ended up creating a new virtual environment `python -m venv .venv` then activate it `source .venv/bin/activate`
3. I was able to install onnxruntime 1.17.1 using
   `SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=0 pip install --no-cache-dir "onnxruntime>=1.17.1"`
4. Anaconda's env is preventing llama-index-core 0.10.13 and llama-index-vector-stores-chroma 0.1.4 to be installed at the same time for some weird reason. So I had to force using `SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=0 pip install --no-cache-dir "llama-index-core>=0.10.13"` and `SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=0 pip install --no-cache-dir "llama-index-vector-stores-chroma>=0.1.4"`
5. Finally, you should be able to `pip install llama-index`. It should automatically try to install the newest version 0.10.13.post1 as for 02/27/2024.

For code, with the new update, the old code
`from llama_index.core.llms import ChatMessage, ChatResponse`

Now switched to
`from llama_index.core.base.llms.types import ChatMessage, ChatResponse`

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement onnxruntime>=1.17.1 (from versions: 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 1.10.0, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.1, 1.14.1, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for onnxruntime>=1.17.1

Comment: ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'llama-index-core 0.10.13'

Comment: @zaghadon i figured out that issue. `"llama-index-core 0.10.13"` etc. should be replaced by `"llama-index-core>=0.10.13"`

Comment: @SwagZ - I followed all of the steps, using the modified syntax in my comment above (please edit your answer). I then deactivated the venv, activated my conda env, and tried to upgrade, but got the same results.

Comment: I was able to solve this using this workaround: `conda install onnxruntime -c conda-forge`. I got it from this thread: https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/11037

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install onnxruntime --upgrade
```

It will install onnxruntime-1.16.3 or greater and will replace older versions that cause this issue.

Comment: this does not help at all. The error clearly wants onnxruntime of version >=1.17.0. Installing onnxruntime-1.16.3 does nothing